# Ansible: How to stop an EC2 instance started by a different playbook

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

If I start an EC2 instance (or set of instances) in Ansible, how can I later refer to that instance (or set) and terminate them?

This is across playbooks.  So, in one playbook I've already started an instance, then later, I want to terminate those instances with another playbook.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You will need to do something like this (working example):

terminate.yml:

```
 - name: terminate single instance
   hosts: all
   tasks:
     - action: ec2_facts
     - name: terminating single instance
       local_action:
         module: ec2
         state: 'absent'
         region: us-east-1
         instance_ids: "{{ ansible_ec2_instance_id }}"
```

to terminate instance at address instance.example.com:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i instance.example.com, terminate.yml
```

The [ec2 facts module](http://docs.ansible.com/ec2_facts_module.html) will query the metadata service on the instance to get the instance ID.
The [ec2 module](http://docs.ansible.com/ec2_module.html) is used to terminate the instance by its ID.

Note the ec2_facts module needs to run on the instance(s) that you want to terminate and you will probably want to use an inventory file or [dynamic inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_dynamic_inventory.html) to lookup the instance(s) by tag instead of addressing them by hostname.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if we are going to use the dynamic inventory, then I recommend using **count_tags** and **exact_count** with the ec2 module when creating the instances with **create.yml**:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files: { ./env.yml }
  tasks:
  - name: Provision a set of instances
    ec2:
        instance_type: "{{ item.value.instance_type }}"
        image: "{{ image }}"
        region: "{{ region }}"
        vpc_subnet_id: "{{ item.value.vpc_subnet_id }}"
        tenancy: "{{ tenancy }}"
        group_id: "{{ group_id }}"
        key_name: "{{ key_name }}"
        wait: true
        instance_tags:
           Name: "{{ env_id }}"
           Type: "{{ item.key }}"
        count_tag:
           Type: "{{ item.key }}"
        exact_count: "{{ item.value.count }}"
    with_dict: "{{ servers }}"
    register: ec2
```

The env.yml file has all those variables, and the servers dictionary:

```
---
env_id: JaxDemo
key_name: JaxMagicKeyPair
image: "ami-xxxxxxxx"
region: us-east-1
group_id: "sg-xxxxxxxx,sg-yyyyyyyy,sg-zzzzzzzz"
tenancy: dedicated

servers:
   app:
      count: 2
      vpc_subnet_id: subnet-xxxxxxxx
      instance_type: m3.medium
   httpd:
      count: 1
      vpc_subnet_id: subnet-yyyyyyyy
      instance_type: m3.medium
   oracle:
      count: 1
      vpc_subnet_id: subnet-zzzzzzzz
      instance_type: m4.4xlarge
```

Now, if you want to change the number of servers, just change the count in the servers dictionary.  If you want to delete all of them, we all the counts to 0.

Or, if you prefer, copy the **create.yml** file to **delete_all.yml**, and replace

```
exact_count: "{{ item.value.count }}"
```

with

```
exact_count: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll extend the answer of [jarv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3930609/jarv) with a working example, in which you can terminate single or a group of server(s) with ansible playbook.

Let's suppose, you want to terminate a instance(s), that fall under the delete group in your hosts file:

```
[delete]
X.X.X.X # IP address of an EC2 instance
```

Now your playbook will be look like this(in my case, I named it "ec2_terminate.yml"):

```
---
- hosts: delete
  gather_facts: True
  user: ubuntu
  sudo: True
  tasks:

    # fetch instance data from the metadata servers in ec2
    - ec2_facts:

    # just show the instance-id
    - debug: msg= "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_ec2_instance_id'] }}"

- hosts: delete
  gather_facts: True
  connection: local
  vars:
    region: "us-east-1"
  tasks:
    - name: destroy all instances
      ec2: state='absent'
           region={{ region }}
           instance_ids={{ item }}
           wait=true
      with_items: hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_ec2_instance_id']
```

Now run this playbook like this:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts ec2_terminate.yml
```

Comment: with only 1 server, this seems to work for me after running ec2_facts: {{ ansible_ec2_instance_id }}

Answer (score 0):

When you originally create those instances, make sure to uniquely identify/tag them.
Then on the following runs you can use dynamic inventory script to populate your host list, as seen here http://docs.ansible.com/intro_dynamic_inventory.html and then terminate instances matching your tags.